# Twitter oAUth authentication for Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs

I am trying to connect to a Twitter which requires oAuth. Does Sencha Touch allow for that and if so does anyone have an example to share?

Answer (score 6):

I've got an example using phone gap - 
http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=40

it logs into twitter and saves the token for future use... should point you in the right direction!

hope that helps :)

Comment: you can use the concept, phonegap and sencha can work together, but if you look at how the oAuth happens storing the data, and doing authorization you should be in good shape...

Answer (score 0):

follow this tutorial,

[Twitter oauth Integration](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms)

i had already implemented it in my phone gap application. 
it also works for sencha touch.